# How does the Preferred Workflow setting work?

Tags: 2013, schema, workflow

In SDL Tridion 2013, in a schema's workflow tab, we can select an option for components based on this schema to "require approval by a Bundle Workflow Process." We can then set a "Preferred Workflow Process (Definition) for this Bundle."

How does this setting impact bundle workflow in the Content Manager Explorer (and Experience Manager, if different)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If set, items based on the Schema cannot be checked-in except by workflow. The idea being that you add the items to a Bundle and then Start Workflow on that Bundle when you are ready for all of the items inside to go through workflow.

Instead of being checked-in, the items will be "Waiting for Workflow" instead - even before you add it to a Bundle. It will be unlocked, so other people can continue editing it, with the caveat that they need to take over all previous changes too (so if they Undo Checkout, they throw away all changes -- not just their own). The CME and Experience Manager will prompt you to "take ownership" when you attempt to edit such an item.

The "preferred" part means that you could choose a different process for some items, but Experience Manager will only suggest Bundles that have Schemas that use the same process.

Comment: Ok, so Experience Manager will by default only show Bundles that have workflow, but the preferred option hides Bundles that don't match the same process. Perfect and thanks for the full explanation, Peter. I anticipate we'll see more questions about these "reserved" items without owners. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This setting will prevent checking-in. Item has to be added to workflow bundle (bundle which has bundle schema with associated workflow peocess definition) and be checked in by workflow. Keep in mind that it is "preferred" process definition, so in practice any workflow bundle will be sufficient

Comment: Nice, this means authors would have a functional way to choose different workflows and the workflow definitions themselves can be more modular.