# How does schema workflow option "Preferred Workflow Process" work specifically?

Tags: 2013, workflow

I'm working on Tridion 2013 Workflow.

On schema, there is an option "Preferred Workflow Process for this Bundle" on Workflow tab.
But I can't understand how it works, so I read the following post.

[How does the Preferred Workflow setting work?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-does-the-preferred-workflow-setting-work)

Then I imagine the following:

If a Workflow Process is selected in the option, only Bundles that are using a Bundle Schema that are using same Workflow Process are displayed when clicking "Add to Bundle" button on Experience Manager.

But when I tried, all Bundles are displayed in "Assign this item to a Bundle" list, including ones that are not associated with "Preferred Workflow Process".
Also I could add the component into a Bundle that is not "Preferred" and execute Workflow normally.

How does "Preferred Workflow Process" option work specifically?

Answer (score 4):

The preferred workflow process mean that even if you edit the component and save it, the component will have to enter in a Bundle Workflow Process to be finally checked-in.
If you have this setting in a schema, when you save a component based on that schema you will receive a message saying that the component has to enter in a Bundle Workflow.
If the Component doesn't complete the Bundle Workflow, will appear as checked out, but a user can still open and modify the component (receiving the same message again).
You can still add the component to a different Bundle

One thing you can test is if you add the component to a bundle configured with a different workflow than the one setup in the schema and complete the workflow process, verify if the component appears as checked-in or has to mandatory be added to a Bundle that has the same workflow process definition than the one defined in the schema. That won't take long to test.

Comment: Even if a component is added to a Bundle that have different workflow process from "Preferred" one, the component is checked in when the Bundle's workflow finishes.
So I still cannot understand how "Preferred Workflow Process" option works.
Tridion manual says "Doing so makes that Process Definition more prominent to the user when they add the item to a Bundle".
But "Preferred" Bundle is not "prominent" because it looks same as anoter Bundles on "Available Bundles" list when adding a component to a Bundle.